# keep service active after activity stopped

Tags: wear-os

I am writing an app for Android wear, which vibrates the watch. The problem is that the vibration stopes when the screen goes off.

I tried creating a bound service, but this gets killed as soon as I disconnect from it.

I tried making it sticky, but this does not work as well (see code bellow):

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d("BPM", "Service command start = sticky");
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

How can I convince wearos to keep the service alive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually - I ended keeping the screen on for my activity.

Trick was using:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Which also work as expected on WearOS. Not strictly answering the question - but solved the original problem. Giving myself the green marker.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to use foreground service with notification.

Comment: arg... yes, seems logical. Do you have any idea how to prevent from screen turning off on WearOS? (note to self: check a wakelock)

Comment: All that come to my mind can be found here:
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock
Additionaly for activities it is possible to use WearableActivity and setAmbientEnabled method.